# Azure Function Node JS unable to read Application Settings returns undefined for process.env.variable_name

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions, application-settings

Application settings contain the Azure Storage Account Connection string. The function app is designed to generate the SAS token. Have set the Azure Storage Account connection string as part of the Application settings to the function app. When the application is hosted on Azure it returns undefined.

However, the same connection string which is stored in local.settings.json is able to read when running locally.

Bellow is the code to read the connection string in Azure Function

```
let connectionString = process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING;
 context.log("context - Connection String ", connectionString);
```

This returns the correct connection string when running locally but not when published to server.
Local.Settings.json code
[image]

Function app Application Settings

[image]

Comment: The function app has been created using Terraform Provider 3.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the Function app couldn't read the Application Settings is that when the application was created using terraform's **azurerm_linux_function_app** module I failed to mention **application_stack** settings. However, the deployed code was able to function but it was not able to read the application settings. This is evident from the application settings configuration page in Azure Portal.

[image]

In the picture above we couldn't find the **FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME** this settings will be placed by the Terraform if we have correctly specified its **application_stack**. Also, note that when the function app is deployed via Visual Studio code these are correctly specified. In the same way, when the Function is created via Azure Portal it is again set correctly.

Bellow is the correct code for **azurerm_linux_function_app** for node function app.

[image]

After deploying the above code then the application settings are reflected as below.

[image]

So ensure that this value is correctly reflected when we can read value from process.env object.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue with connection string being empty when deployed to azure.

I have fixed this issue by pasting the the connection string of storage account into the application Setting as below :

I have clicked on connection string name and then pasted the connection string over there as below.

[image]

Then when I set the value in portal, it worked for me, try to do this way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue was with deployment via terraform. Please see the answer.